# Riverpod notifier Provider not keeping state

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have 2 lines of code where I set the value of riverpod notifier providers. The 2 lines of code are in a file called trxn_details_screen.dart.

The Globals class is in the file globals.dart.

The first line always sets newTrxn to "false" as expected.
When the second line executes, newTrxn is set back to "true" but I don't understand why because it has nothing to do with the variable, newTrxn.

```
ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier).updatenewTrxn(false);
ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier).updatecurrentTrxnId(snapshot.data?.docs[index].id);
```

Here is the code where the 2 lines above are found:

```
body: SafeArea(
          child: FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot?>(
              future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('company')
                  .doc(ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).companyId)
                  .collection('trxns')
                  .get(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return snapshot.hasData
                    ? ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data?.size,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: ListTile(
                              isThreeLine: true,
                              title: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    'Client: ${snapshot.data?.docs[index]['clientFName'] ?? 'n/a'} ${snapshot.data?.docs[index]['clientLName'] ?? 'n/a'}',
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                        color: Colors.blueAccent),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              subtitle: Text.rich(
                                TextSpan(
                                  text:
                                      '${snapshot.data?.docs[index]['propertyAddress'] ?? 'n/a'}, '
                                      '${snapshot.data?.docs[index]['propertyCity'] ?? 'n/a'}, '
                                      '${snapshot.data?.docs[index]['propertyState'] ?? 'n/a'}',
                                  children: <TextSpan>[
                                    TextSpan(
                                      text:
                                          '\nPrice: ${snapshot.data?.docs[index]['contractPrice'] == null ? 'n/a' : snapshot.data?.docs[index]['contractPrice']}\nStatus: ${snapshot.data?.docs[index]['trxnStatus'] ?? 'n/a'}',
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                          color: Colors.blueGrey),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              trailing: Text(
                                  'MLS#: ${snapshot.data?.docs[index]['mlsNumber'] ?? 'n/a'}\n${snapshot.data?.docs[index]['clientType']}'),
                              onTap: () {
                                //MainScreen.of(context)?.setIndex(2);  // Added this for BottomNavigationBar sync
                                ref
                                    .read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                                    .updatenewTrxn(false);
                                ref
                                    .read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                                    .updatecurrentTrxnId(
                                        snapshot.data?.docs[index].id);

                                Navigator.of(context).push(
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) =>
                                        const TransactionDetailScreen(),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      )
                    : const Text('No Date');
              }),
        ),
```

In the Globals copyWith code, if I write the line to be
bool newTrxn = true, then ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).newTrxn gets set to "true" when the next line of code is executed.

If I set bool? newTrxn, then ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).newTrxn gets set to "null" when the next line of code is executed.

Here is the Globals class:

```
class Globals {
  final String? currentUid;
  final String? currentUEmail;
  final String? userDocumentId;
  final String? companyId;
  final String? mlsId;
  final String? currentTrxnId;
  final String? currentCompanyName;
  final String? currentCompanyState;
  final String? currentUserId;
  final String? currentUserState;
  final String? currentUserName;
  final String? selectedState;
  final String? selectedUserState;
  final String? selectedTrxnState;
  final String? selectedCompany;
  final String? selectedUser;
  final String? userBusinessType;
  final int? targetScreen;
  final bool? newEvent;
  final bool? newTrxn;
  final bool? newUser;
  final bool newCompany;
  final bool? addCompany;

  Globals({
    this.currentUid,
    this.currentUEmail,
    this.userDocumentId,
    this.companyId,
    this.mlsId,
    this.currentTrxnId,
    this.currentCompanyName,
    this.currentCompanyState,
    this.currentUserId,
    this.currentUserState,
    this.currentUserName,
    this.selectedState,
    this.selectedUserState,
    this.selectedTrxnState,
    this.selectedCompany,
    this.selectedUser,
    this.userBusinessType,
    this.targetScreen,
    this.newEvent,
    this.newTrxn,
    this.newUser,
    this.addCompany,
    required this.newCompany,
  });

  Globals copyWith({
    String? currentUid,
    String? currentUEmail,
    String? userDocumentId,
    String? companyId,
    String? mlsId,
    String? currentTrxnId,
    String? currentCompanyName,
    String? currentCompanyState,
    String? currentUserId,
    String? currentUserState,
    String? currentUserName,
    String? selectedState,
    String? selectedUserState,
    String? selectedTrxnState,
    String? selectedCompany,
    String? selectedUser,
    String? userBusinessType,
    int? targetScreen,
    bool newEvent = true,   <<< PROBLEM
    bool newTrxn = true,   <<< PROBLEM
    bool newUser = true,   <<< PROBLEM
    bool newCompany = true,   <<< PROBLEM
    bool addCompany = false,   <<< PROBLEM
  }) {
    return Globals(
      currentUid: currentUid ?? this.currentUid,
      currentUEmail: currentUEmail ?? this.currentUEmail,
      userDocumentId: userDocumentId ?? this.userDocumentId,
      companyId: companyId ?? this.companyId,
      mlsId: mlsId ?? this.mlsId,
      currentTrxnId: currentTrxnId ?? this.currentTrxnId,
      currentCompanyName: currentCompanyName ?? this.currentCompanyName,
      currentCompanyState: currentCompanyState ?? this.currentCompanyState,
      currentUserId: currentUserId ?? this.currentUserId,
      currentUserState: currentUserState ?? this.currentUserState,
      currentUserName: currentUserName ?? this.currentUserName,
      selectedState: selectedState ?? this.selectedState,
      selectedUserState: selectedUserState ?? this.selectedUserState,
      selectedTrxnState: selectedTrxnState ?? this.selectedTrxnState,
      selectedCompany: selectedCompany ?? this.selectedCompany,
      selectedUser: selectedUser ?? this.selectedUser,
      userBusinessType: userBusinessType ?? this.userBusinessType,
      targetScreen: targetScreen ?? this.targetScreen,
      newEvent: newEvent,
      newTrxn: newTrxn,
      newUser: newUser,
      newCompany: newCompany,
      addCompany: addCompany,
    );
  }
}
```

In the Globals copyWith(), I don't know how to handle the bool type variables. Whatever I put in this line, bool? newTrxn, is what the notifier provider ends up with.

How do I handle the bools in the copyWith() function so they don't reset the state variables back to what is in the Globals class?

I hope this all makes sense.

Thanks

UPDATE:
I think this has something to do with the ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider.Notifier).updateNewTrxn() being called inside the onTap method, which is in the build method.

I moved the code out into a method but newTrxn is still being reset to whatever newTrxn equals in the copyWith function.

How do I fix this?

This is the new function which is outside the build: method

```
setGlobals() {
    ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier).updatenewTrxn(false);
  }
```

Here is the new version of the onTap method:

```
onTap: () {
                                setGlobals(); <<< NEW FUNCTION
                                ref
                                    .read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                                    .updatecurrentTrxnId(
                                        snapshot.data?.docs[index].id);
                                Navigator.of(context).push(
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) =>
                                        const TransactionDetailScreen(),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
```